# Is it logically correct to refer your husband as bro

Tags: word-usage, american-english

Is it logically correct if a wife addresses his husband as "bro"? I have seen some people doing that in non-native English speakers. It's rare though. Although technically if one looks at the dictionary one definition of "bro" is "it's used to address in a friendly way or to a male friend".Considering that it seems fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: Logical, I don't know. Hilarious, yes.

Comment: Casual speech is not ruled by logic. You can call your husband, father, mother, sister, cousin, cat, or dog, 'bro', if you want to, and they don't mind. Whether you agree with the previous statement, or disagree with it, is a matter of opinion, and opinion-based questions are off-topic for this site.

Comment: People don't always obey logic or dictionaries in very casual or friendly speech, especially with loved ones or friends. A few years ago a couple came into our circle of friends. The husband called his wife 'Foxie', even though her real name was Carol. It's not logical (she is a human, not a fox, although she is definitely a 'fox'). After a while we and all our friends started calling her Foxie as well. My wife learned the spelling from an SMS from her.

Comment: Insofar as bro is usually used by men,  I really think that a wife would not address the husband as bro unless she trying to make a point about something. That then makes her like his male peer, which might help her in a particular situation where they are arguing.

Answer (score 1):

"Bro" is used mostly by one man to refer to a friend who is as close as a brother. It's very casual and is typical of 20-year-old drinking buddies.

It would be very unusual for a wife to refer to a husband as "bro".

If it ever occurred, it would almost certainly be ironic.  Perhaps with the implication "If you don't treat me like you should treat your wife, I will make fun of you and use a term that is so strange that it mocks you" It suggest the the husband is acting like a juvenile drunk, rather than responsible person.

A husband isn't a "male friend".  That is a quite different relationship.

"Logic" doesn't apply.  Logic is about how propositions can be combined with "and" or "implies".  There is no more "logic" in this situation than deep sea diving.

But, if this is an actual question, why not ask your husband if he wants to be called "bro".  His opinion matters more than mine.